# Does using PresentViewController release the presenting ViewController from memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I was wondering if using PresentViewController releases the presenting viewController from the stack, I could not find any information about this in the documentation.

If it doesn't, does DismissViewController release the previous viewcontroller?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I am not sure why you put this question on hold. My question is more conceptual: **I need to know how to release a UIViewController from memory**. I could not find any information in the iOS documentation.

Comment: For the followup question, why would dismissing release the presenting view controller? Do you mean would it release the presented view controller?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presenting a view controller does not release the presenting view controller. Why would it?

Dismissing the presented view controller of course does not release the original presenting view controller but it certainly should result in the dismissed view controller being released. If it is not, then there is a problem. A typical issue is a reference cycle in the presented view controller.

Comment: How do I release a viewController from memory?

Comment: Like any other object - release all references so the reference count goes to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Presenting a modal view controller puts the new view controller on top of the previous view controller. When you then dismiss the modal, the old view controller is revealed again.

If the old view controller was released then it would not be around to show again when the modal is dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

No, the view controller that does the presenting does not get released, however its view might, and if its view does get released, then `viewDidLoad` will be called again when the presented view controller gets dismissed. Your code has to be ready for that possibility.

If, for example, you create a model object in `viewDidLoad`, that object may be destroyed and replaced by a new instance when the view controller it presented gets dismissed.

Comment: So when you say the view might, on what conditions will it be released? I need to make sure the view gets released every time, so that the view refreshes.

Comment: If your goal is to make sure your view refreshes, then you asked the wrong question. You should have asked how to refresh the presenter's view after the presenting view controller dismisses. The conditions for releasing views is unspecified.

Comment: Okay, Say I want to simply refresh (re-instantiate) a UIViewController and release the old instance from memory. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no situation where that would be a good idea. Ask the question whose answer will solve the problem you are having.